# view the html source of an xml document transformed by xsl

Tags: html, xml, debugging, xslt, browser

This is a fairly simple case. I have an xml document, linked to an xsl stylesheet, that can be viewed in a web browser. Now that the output is not really what I expected, so I want to look at the (output) html code to see what happened. However, when I say "view source", the browsers just throw the original xml file at me.
Please show me how to view the html source :)

**updated**
Actually I can view it with Chrome (by right clicking and say "Inspect element"), but that's somewhat browser dependent. Additionally I don't want to install anything just for this small treat. Is there any general solution (i.e. something that works with all (or most) browsers)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Firefox, if you select the entire text (eg Ctrl-A) on the page, you can right-click and select "View Selection Source" which will show you what's been rendered, rather than the document source.

Answer (score 2):

If the browser is Firefox, you can install Firebug and view generated HTML.

Comment: +1 I think you are using IE. Try the above in Firefox with Firebug addin. Will really help you solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

In IE-11, press F12 to open Developer Tools, then choose Debugger from the menu.
This displays the transformed xml.
I don't know which version of IE first added this feature.

Comment: Just want to document this: A classic ASP application using `<frame>` to show the transformed XML page. In this case, the Debugger tab shows only the top level, but not into the frame level. Choose 'DOM Explorer' instead. You can drill down to each frame and then, of course, to each page.

Answer (score 0):

Download this viewing [tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=D23C1D2C-1571-4D61-BDA8-ADF9F6849DF9&displaylang=en) for Internet Explorer from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, this can be checked by right click and click inspect element option.